# Limiting rotation with modulo vs. loop

Tags: c#, optimization, rotation

While adding Unit Tests to legacy code, I found this construct:

```
    double rotationX = Math.Abs(newRotationX % 360 + 360) % 360;
```

It basically forces the rotation to be a value in the range `[0, 360)`. Negative numbers become positive (`-1` should become `359`), and large numbers are limited (`725` should become `5`).

Would a loop be more efficient?

```
double rotationX = newRotation;
while (rotationX < 0)
    rotationX += 360;
while (rotationX >= 360)
    rotationX -= 360;
```

... or even using a single `%` instead?

```
double rotationX = newRotation % 360; // Value can be -359..359
if (rotationX < 0)
    rotationX += 360; // Negative values are now > 0
```

Comment: Efficiency is definitely not anything you should be considering on a tiny scale like this. The original is probably optimal anyway. Your second example will give wrong results on very large negative numbers.

Comment: @Magus: While I agree that early optimization is usually a bad thing, we've found that this method can get called once per frame (around 60 times per second) while a user holds onto a rotation gizmo. For this reason, we are trying to optimize parts that get called frequently.

Comment: Yes, but there's no way simple math operations are going to be slower than a loop. Processors are made specifically to do a **lot** of math operations per second.

Comment: If you are trying to optimize your code its best to profile it first to identify sub-optimal code rather than guessing by the frequency of calls.

Comment: If the full circle is multiple of base 2, e.g., 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, ..., 512, masker operator `&` can be used. But alas, it's 360 instead of say 256 or 512. But if you happen to rotate numbers using base 2, you can merely use the `&` to rotate number instead of using modulo+addition+modulo. First, substract the divisor by 1, and then mask that to number. Example, for 512 rotation, use 511 as masker:

`-1 & 511 == 511; -2 & 511 == 510; -3 & 511 = 509; 1 & 511 == 1; 2 & 511 == 2; 511 & 511 == 511; 512 & 511 == 0; 515 & 511 == 3`. Here's a sample fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DedpF2

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a really minor issue, and the compiler will probably do it's best to optimize it.

If it really floats your boat, you could quickly mock up a test and benchmark, but there are oh so many things to keep in mind to make it valid, that it probably isn't worth it.

Also:

Premature optimization is the root of evil posts and article:

- [question on programmers.stack exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)
- [article](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)
- there are plenty on SO as well...

You probably have better things to worry about with your legacy code I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the `Math.Abs` call is unnecessary, because the modulus of a negative number will get the value somewhere between -359 and 0 and then adding 360 on top of that, you will be in the positive range.  The final modulus 360 would need to remain to deal with positive number that don't need the 360 added to them.  In doing this you remove one of the calls on the stack.

```
var rotationX = 
    (newRotationX % 360 + 360) // puts any negative number into the positive range
    % 360; // puts any positive numbers back into the 0-359 range
```

And dropping down to a single modulus operation as in your second example, may very well be more optimal.  But you really need to profile your code to figure out what option performs the best.

Comment: True that `Math.Abs` is redundant, but wouldn't a singular modulo and then an `if` statement be more efficient than an addition followed by another modulo?

Comment: @OnlineCop As I stated in my answer, it is quite possible a single modulus operation followed by an `if` and then adding 360 when negative may be more optimal.  But without [profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) the code to see which option performs better, you are just guessing.